# Convert python list to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying convert my list to dictionary in python. I have list l

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and I want convert it to dictionary d

```
d['a'] = []
d['b'] = []
d['c'] = []
d['d'] = []
```

I was trying

```
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    d[i][0]=l(i)
```

but that don't work. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't work, and the error message `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` would have been a good starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it a bit simpler than that, you want to loop over your list, and then assign your iterator `i` (which will be each value in your list) as the key to each dictionary entry.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

d = {}
for i in l:
    d[i] = []


print(d) # {'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': [], 'd': []}
```

With the above understood, you can now actually simplify this in to one line as:

```
{k: [] for k in l}
```

The above is called a dictionary comprehension. You can read about it [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Answer (score 2):

you should do this instead.

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

my_d = {letter:[] for letter in li}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
d = {key: [] for key in l}
```